# How to inform user they have created a duplicate record, and ask if they want to overwrite?

Tags: vba, duplicates

I have a workbook and have created command buttons. I have successfully created VBA's to 2 buttons but am struggling with a duplicates code. I am transferring data from specific cells from worksheets onto a worksheet entitled "Master" my file is auto-created from a save command, which auto-saves the worksheet as an invoice (c10) then project ref (a12). I am trying to write code into my existing VBA to tell me that a duplicate is being added, and ask me if I want to overwrite it?

Here is how far I have got and I have spent hours on the duplicates function, trying to correct it but I keep falling down. All other duplicates are allowed in the row are allowed except ("C10"). I just can't make this work for me.
Please can anyone help?

```vb
    Dim Item As Range, DataEntry As Range
    Dim Data() As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim DataRow As Long
    Dim wsMaster As Worksheet
    
    Set wsMaster = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")
    
    Set DataEntry = ActiveSheet.Range("C10,A3,A12,E10,F33")
   
    Dim assetIDRange, a As Range

    For Each Item In DataEntry
        i = i + 1
        ReDim Preserve Data(1 To i)

        Data(i) = Item.Value
    Next
    
    DataRow = wsMaster.Cells(wsMaster.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
       wsMaster.Cells(DataRow, 1).Resize(1, DataEntry.Cells.Count).Value = Data
    MsgBox "Record Added To Master", 48, "Record Added"
End Sub
```

Comment: Which is the entry to be checked? To check what against what?

Comment: Sounds like you could use a database, like MS Access at least.

Comment: Hi HackSlash, i agree but unfortunately I don't have the function on my laptop (yet)..working on the boss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```vb
Sub InsertUpdate()

    Dim Item As Range, DataEntry As Range
    Dim Data() As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim wsMaster As Worksheet
    Dim m, c As Range, action
    
    Set wsMaster = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")
    
    Set DataEntry = ActiveSheet.Range("C10,A3,A12,E10,F33")
   
    ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To DataEntry.Cells.Count)
    For Each Item In DataEntry.Cells
        i = i + 1
        Data(1, i) = Item.Value
    Next
    
    'existing row with same C10 value?
    m = Application.Match(Data(1, 1), wsMaster.Columns("a"), 0)
    
    If Not IsError(m) Then 'found existing match?
        If MsgBox("Replace existing entry for '" & Data(1, 1) & "' ?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
            Set c = wsMaster.Columns("a").Cells(m)
            action = "Updated"
        End If
    Else
        Set c = wsMaster.Cells(wsMaster.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        action = "Added"
    End If
    
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        c.Resize(1, UBound(Data, 2)).Value = Data
        MsgBox "Record " & action & " To Master", 48, "Record Added"
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Why should `Data(1, 1)` be the one to be checked?

Comment: thank you so much, this is working perfectly now! I have been at this for days.

Comment: @FaneDuru - from the original question: "All other duplicates are allowed in the row are allowed except ("C10")."  Value from C10 is in `Data(1,1)`

Comment: @Narkyknickers Do you need checking only the value in "C10"?

Comment: Obviously, my English is too poor to understand that from "which auto-saves the worksheet as an invoice (c10) then project ref (a12)"...

Comment: @FaneDuru - it's right there in the second paragraph...

Comment: Ups! You are right. Not only English is my problem... :) Voted up for attention and not only.